# Sending contents of an xml file as response using php

Tags: php, xml

I wrote xml to a file using php, and then I sent the file data as a response to the client's browser.
But, I'm getting the following error:
**XML Parsing Error: not well-formed**
Below, is my code. Any way to fix this?

```
$file= fopen("result.xml", "w");
$_xml ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>";
$_xml .="<friends>";
$timestamp = time();
$_xml.="<date>".date("F jS, Y", $timestamp)."</date>"; //Like December 23rd, 2009
$_xml .="<total>".$totalResults."</total>";
foreach($friendList as $key => $value) { /*$friendList contains key value pairs*/
    $_xml.="<friend>";
    $_xml.="<name>".$key."</name>";
    $_xml.="<webpage>".$value."</webpage>";
    $_xml.="</friend>";
}
$_xml .="</friends>";
fwrite($file,$_xml);
fclose($file);

//Send the xml file as response
header('Content-type: text/xml');
readfile('result.xml');
```

Thank You

Comment: Try posting the actual XML. There's probably just an error in that. Also, why are you saving it to a file? Why not just echo $_xml?

Answer (score 4):

The snippet of code you posted works fine without any data in `$friendList`, so the problem lies with your data.

I'm going to guess that you're outputting URLs inside your `<webpage></webpage>` tags, which could contain characters such as `&`.  XML requires that the `& ' " > <` characters be escaped.  Fortunately, [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) does exactly that.

Try using this:

```
$_xml.="<webpage>".htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES)."</webpage>";
```

It's not a bad idea to escape your other pieces of data as well.

Comment: You also can try `CDATA` block: `$_xml.="<webpage><![CDATA[$value]]></webpage>";`

Answer (score 1):

You have a closing "friends" tag that is never opened. Change the relevant snipper to:

```
$_xml .="<friends>";
foreach($friendList as $key => $value) { /*$friendList contains key value pairs*/
    $_xml.="<friend>";
    $_xml.="<name>".$key."</name>";
    $_xml.="<webpage>".$value."</webpage>";
    $_xml.="</friend>";
}
$_xml .="</friends>";
```

Using somethring like [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) makes it much easier and cleaner to write this kind of code:

```
$xml_writer = new XMLWriter();
$xml_writer->openMemory();

$xml_writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8', 'yes');
...
$xml_writer->startElement('friends');
...
$xml_writer->endElement(); //friends
...
$data = $xml_writer->outputMemory();
echo($data);
```

Comment: I agree with using an OO-style interface to write this data out, rather than raw XML, but if you check near the top of his code the "friends" node is actually the root node, and was the first thing opened after the XML declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Roland. I used XMLWriter now, but i still get the not well formed error. My new code is http://pastebin.com/m52da93a .Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the array `$friendList` has keys and/or values have tag(s) in them. If that is the case our XML string `$_xml` will not be a valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

The XML im getting is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<friends><date>December 23rd, 2009</date><total>2</total><friend><name>ABC</name><url>http://www.somesite.org/abc</url></friend><friend><name>PQR</name><url>http://www.somesite.org/pqr</url></friend></friends>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to write into a file before serving it. Just output it directly to the client:

```
$_xml .="</friends>";
//Send the xml file as response
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $_xml;
```

Comment: The reason i want to write to the file is, i dont want to dynamically generate the xml for every page request.

Comment: @Jimg That is exactly the same as you are doing at the moment. The only difference is you are writing to the same file instead of displaying it directly on the page. Will you be using the result.xml for some other purpose?